Labour market rigidity
I really doubt my understanding of the wage rigidity in the labour market(with the standard upward sloping $L^s$ curve and Downward sloping $L^d$ curve).
So In this scenario, we have that the labour market that will not clear above the wage $\overline{W}$
Lets discuss what will happen at ${W^1}$
Here is my attempt,
I think as $W^1> \overline{W}$, the labour market will not clear and the firms will hire only $l^1=L^d(W^1)$ and $(L^1-l^1)$ amounts for the involuntary unemployment(as $L^1$ are willing to work at $W^1$ but there is no firm willing to provide work)

and for case two, as $W_2<\overline{W}$, the market will clear in a way such that the Labour demand will fall and $W_2$ will become the new labour market equilibrium. Now the involuntary unemployment is zero

Is my understanding about the rigidities and the above comparative statics exercises any correct?
Any help is much appreciated!
PS. Sorry for the pixelated graphs, I made those on overleaf and couldn't figure out a better way to export them:-[
